# how to find distance by road between two geo points in offline for android

Tags: android

i want to measure the distance by road  between two places provided the latitude and longitude of the places.My android application is going to be used by offline users.I think Google map API can't be used in this case.Please help me friends....

Comment: At any moment of time, do you have both position coordinates with you in hand?

Comment: no,only one position cocrdinates in my hand and other position cocrdinates is user's current location which retrieving dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847353/use-google-maps-offline-in-an-app#5896100), how to use google map in offline app. This is based on [osmdroid](https://code.google.com/p/osmdroid/) and also be aware of [Google terms of use](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/terms.html) googleMap.

Comment: in prerequisites for osmdroid library it is mentioned that it requires internet permission which is not allowed in my application(it's an offline app).Also i dont want to show map.i want the calculation of distance by road  between the places.can you please guide me more specific to my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so here you go, being in offline mode you can only rely on this method for retrieving user current coordinates.

1. Passive Provider :- This is very fast, but its accurate only if some other app would have requested location of user just before you requesting.
2. GPS Provider: this is slow and generally only works in open areas, at most it might take 10-20 sec to receive coordinates from satellite
3. You can also use network triangulation, from cell towers they are faster than GPS provider.

Based on above mentioned procedures you can write a function which will first try to fetch user current location from fastest provider, than task would be to verify how old is this data, if not recent then you can resort to checking user location parallely from other two methods which ever return you coordinates first is your answer.

Once you have both the coordinates, use Location clasa API distanceTo to find exact distance between them.

I hope this will help you write your logic.

Comment: thanks for your help.Using Location class API  can i get the distance by road between the places ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get distance between two places on the basis of latitude and longitude values in offline mode is to store these values in sqlite file and retrieve from it during execution of application.

You have to prepare one database with columns latitude,longitude and distance between places etc.

You can ask if you have any further queries :)

Comment: among the two places, one place is user's current location which always varies.

Comment: do you have any suggestion to proceed ?

Comment: It is not possible to get current location's latitude and longtitude in offline mode.you have to store this values in sqlite file.

Comment: On way to get it is to use device connected tower location but there's not gaurantee that it will give precise location